# Javascript/Jquery cannot use 0 or 1 as the value of the variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, radio-button

I have a form with a radio select box. There are 6 options. The values of these options are 0 through 5. I'm using Jquery to retrieve the value of the checked radio button upon submission of the form.

```
var nextStatus;
nextStatus = $j('input[name="Status"]:radio:checked').val();
```

This works fine when the status is 2 or above, however, when the status is 0 or 1, it does not set the variable at all. I cannot figure out why it would matter that the value of the radio select button being 0 or 1 would cause jquery/javascript to not set this variable.

```
<label><input type='radio' name='Status' value='0' id='0' />Status0</label><br />
<label><input type='radio' name='Status' value='1' id='1' />Status1</label><br />
<label><input type='radio' name='Status' value='2' id='2' />Status2</label><br />
<label><input type='radio' name='Status' value='3' id='3' />Status3</label><br />
<label><input type='radio' name='Status' value='4' id='4' />Status4</label><br />
<label><input type='radio' name='Status' value='5' id='5' />Status5</label><br />
```

When I use parseInt() on this variable, any status 2 or above comes back fine, but if its the 0 or 1, it returns NaN. When I use typeof() on the var, it returns "string" (after removing parseInt()). I'm totally stumped on this. I SHOULD be able to use a 0 or a 1 as a variable value, should I not?

If I change the values of the radio button to 2 through 7 instead 0 through 5, using firebug,  it works fine. I'd rather not do that as this radio select is programatically generated from a database using foreign keys, and it would be difficult to modify all of that for an issue that to my knowledge shouldn't even be happening.

If anyone has run into this, please help!!!

Comment: It must set the variable to _some_ value. What value are you actually getting? `console.log( nextStatus )`

Comment: that returns: "(an empty string)"

Comment: and if set to status 2 or above, it returns the actual number it should be.

Comment: It's perhaps worth pointing out that, under HTML 4, your `input` elements' `id` s are invalid: they shouldn't *start* with a numeric character.

Comment: @David Thomas, that was exactly it. I appended "Radio" to the front of the ID, and it works perfectly now! I had suspected those ID's might be incorrect, but it didn't seem to be causing issues anywhere else in the code. Thank you!

Comment: One of these days I'll remember: answer *first*, comment *second...* =/ Incidentally, if you changed your doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` (html 5 doctype) the code might've worked as-was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's perhaps worth pointing out that,
>   under HTML 4, your input elements' id
>   s are invalid: they shouldn't start
>   with a numeric character. – David
>   Thomas 14 mins ago

I appened a string to the beginning of the IDs, and this fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JYC3F/1/

Please create a working pared-down test case showing your problem (preferably at JSFiddle).

Comment: Your example definitely does work on that page, I could not however get it working in my code. :/ Thank you for your assistance. It appears to have been caused by the IDs I was using on that radio select.